# Send Image to server using File input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a screen where I am capturing video from camera, taking a snap. I also have a file input and I want to set this option to the captured image from the camera, i.e..snap.

I do not want to store the snap as a cookie and later retrieve it, as it will later make the users computer heavy and will require cleaning everytime.

so the code is

```
<input type="file" id="visitorphoto" name="visitorPhoto" accept="image/*" capture>
```

which is according to this [w3 document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/).

Any Ideas using javascript?

Thanks,
Abhijeet.

Comment: You just want to send the image-file captured by the input to the server? You can not wrap a form around the input and post it? You want to use ajax?

Comment: No ajax dear... but hey i think i can wrap it to the form and send the same...  how? do i put something like '<img form="photo">' something like this..?

Comment: Just wrap a form around that input: <form action=""><input type="file"....></form>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use formData to upload file.
HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="filechooser">
```

Javascript Code

```
function uploadFile() {
    var blobFile = $('#filechooser').files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("fileToUpload", blobFile);

    $.ajax({
       url: "upload.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(response) {
           // .. do something
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
           console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
       }
    });
}
```

Compatibility:
http://caniuse.com/xhr2

Comment: Can we do this using jsp please.?

Comment: Thanks, this helped!

Comment: You have a typo, it's formData, not fd in the "data" field