# Get image and save in storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have an web page which is a profile viewing page. Here I have an blank image. On click of this image I am able to prompt browse image option. But I don't know how to save the image into storage. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="profileImage" >
    <ul>
        <li style="margin-top:5px;">  
            .Hii  
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="file" id="my_file" style="display: none;" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img id="fileupload" name="filetoupload" src="../../static/img/img.png">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fileupload").on("click", function() {
        $("#my_file").click();
    }
```

I tried this below jQuery to save image but is was of no use.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fileupload").on("click",function(){
        $("#my_file").click();
        userImage = document.getElementById('fileupload');
        imgData = getBase64Image(userImage);
        localStorage.setItem("imgData", imgData);
    });    
});
```

My requirement is I should be able to save the image from clicking add image i.e `img.png` in my code. I am using beego as web framework, but i will be happy if this get solved in jQuery or javascript.

Comment: Where is the above failing? What exception do you get?

Comment: no exception. And no action taking place also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/hadadu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)***

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/17711190/383904
function readImage() {
  if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
    var FR= new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
      localStorage.setItem("imgData", event.target.result); // Send to Localstorage
    };       
    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#fileupload").on("click",function(){
    $("#my_file").click().change( readImage );
  });   
});
```

To save that image on server you'll need to send that data to PHP.
PHP can than convert your base64 string to an image.

Otherwise, why not simply send that image using AJAX to a PHP script that will put it inside a server folder?

[Send Image to server using File input type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204621/send-image-to-server-using-file-input-type)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17711190/383904

Comment: where can i specify my location

Comment: You will have to add a specific AJAX call for that, this just saves it in localStorage.

Comment: @vkc what you mean by *Location*? You said you want to store it in localStorage. There you go.

Comment: @vkc if you want to save that image on server, send the image directly to PHP or some other server side language via AJAX.

Comment: selected image should be stored in my local system or in server side in specified path like home/user/picture/stack

Comment: @vkc I really don't get you, If you just read an image from the users machine... why would you want now to save it elsewhere - again on the same machine?

Comment: @vkc ohh than you'll need a PHP script that will do it really easily.

Comment: @vkc also please, next time when you ask questions don't just say "sandwich" but rather "toast sandwich with beacon and mayonnaise" OK? Cause `storage` can mean lot of things.

Comment: Okay...then Shall i close this question. And post new one with specific requirement

Comment: @vkc you don't have to close this question since I've already answered it as-per-question-title. You can ask a new one, but first make sure to search for similar questions, be specific, and show what you tried. Happy coding